# Why should we use" test template" while using "data driver" library in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I'm getting the following error:

```
Calling method '_start_suite' of listener 'Data Driver' failed: Attribute Error: No "Test Template" keyword found for first test case.
```

This is the code that generates that error:

*** Settings ***
Documentation  practice
Library  Data Driver file=../../Test Data/LoginData.xlsx  sheet_name=Sheet 1
Library   Selenium2 Library
Resource   ../../Keywords/Login Keywords.robot

*** Test Cases ***

test case 1->login test with excel

Open  Website in chrome and 
  Login with valid username and 
  Logout Off the application

Comment: Can you please share your code to [provide minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: In the question section with code format, not in the comments...

Answer (score 0):

Goes as per documentation-

> Test cases have to be defined with a **Test Template**. Reason for this
> is, that the **DataDriver** needs to know the names of the test case
> arguments. **Test cases** cannot not have named arguments.But **Keywords** can.

And for the error, **Error: No "Test Template" keyword found for first test case**. It might be because the **Test template** *<keyword_name>* you have defined did not match the *<keyword_name>* defined in the *** Keywords *** section.

And Also note this, which again is as per doc

> The keyword which is used as Test Template must be defined within the
> test suite (in the same *.robot file). If the keyword which is used as
> Test Template is defined in a Resource the DataDriver has no access to
> its arguments names.